# Cashaddr (bech32) to legacy address format convertor for Bitcoin Cash

Tags: bitcoin-cash, base58, bech32-address

Several days ago our bitcoin cash core wallet started to generate addresses using the new format: `bitcoincash:q......` . That's nice and differs from the bitcoin blockchain generated addresses, but some of our users have problems with the new address formats: not all the online exchangers supports the new format and mark it as invalid. 
Is there an ability to show the user his OLD format address alongside with new one? So that we need some kind of convertor between cashaddr/legacy address format standards (maybe that's silly, sorry), or do it via wallet RPC API?

Comment: "Several days ago our bitcoin cash core wallet..." Bitcoin ABC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They should use those:

- cashaddr.org
- cashaddr.bitcoincash.org
- cashaddress.github.io

Or, you can use the [CashAddrJS](https://github.com/bitcoincashjs/bchaddrjs) library to convert between them ([Here](https://github.com/bitcoincashjs/bchaddrjs/dist) are the browser JS).

Unfortunately there's no RPC command to convert addresses. Sorry!

Comment: All that external hosts/services are nice with one security concern: my project must be secure with NO data from "untrusted" external resources (they even are HTTP, so no even MITM attack shield). Who knows, may be that fellows will start to generate their own addresses and my users will happily send the money to that generated addresses... But JS library is another good option (I've used https://github.com/oskyk/cashaddress , rechecked the source: no external web requests, everything is done locally). Your answer answers my initial question, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I've found this project:
https://github.com/oskyk/cashaddress , checked the accounts generated by it using `validateaddress` of my wallet, seems working fine!

Answer (score 0):

I think GDAX (now Coinbase Pro) just remove the `bitcoincash:` prefix before displaying to users. I can confirm this from my Bitcoin Cash deposit address `q...`.

I remember reading that technically the prefix is part of the address, and depending on the implementation, some wallet may not be able to recognize it. While I'm sure Coinbase has done thorough research, I'd just make `usecashaddr=0` for the Bitcoin-ABC wallet