# C# code for Bitcoin Cash address conversion between legacy and new format

Tags: address, bitcoin-cash, c#

I need to convert legacy Bitcoin Cash addresses to new format and back. I am aware of similar [question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/69362/cashaddr-bech32-to-legacy-address-format-convertor-for-bitcoin-cash), but it asks about PRC and has solution using python, JS. I need it done in C# with no dependencies.

Does anyone know a library? Or have working sample?

Answer (score 3):

Just found a [SharpCashAddr library](https://github.com/cashaddress/SharpCashAddr).
Has pure C# implementation of address conversion in both ways.